# Layout inconsistencies in chrome and IE11/Edge

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11, flexbox, angular-material

I have a layout that is working 100% correct in chrome:

[image]

but viewing it in IE 11 or edge it is displaying a extra scrollbar because the page is now bigger than the browser height:

[image]

html:

```
<body ng-app="MyApp" layout="column" layout-fill>

  <div layout="column" layout-fill>

    <md-toolbar class="md-tall-xl">
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <h2 class="md-flex">Toolbar </h2>
      </div>
      <md-tabs class="tab-left-padding">
        <md-tab>
          <md-tab-label>Item One</md-tab-label>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab>
          <md-tab-label>Item two</md-tab-label>
        </md-tab>
      </md-tabs>
    </md-toolbar>    

    <md-content class="visableOverflow bg" layout="row" flex layout-fill layout-margin style="padding:8px;">    

      <md-whiteframe class="md-whiteframe-z1 overTheToolbar working-bg" layout="column" flex>

        <md-content layout="column" layout-margin>

          Lorem ipsum ...

        </md-content>

      </md-whiteframe>   

    </md-content>

  </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
 .bg {
      background-color: #E0E0E0;
    }

    md-toolbar.md-tall-xl {
      height: 192px;
      min-height: 192px;
      max-height: 192px;
    }

    .overTheToolbar {
      margin-top: -72px!important;
      z-index: 3;
    }

    .visableOverflow {
      overflow: visible;
    }

    .working-bg {
      background-color: white;
    }

    .tab-left-padding {
      padding-left: 15px;
    }
```

I Tried to get IE11/Edge to render it the same as chrome does but can't seem to get it to work. I did check https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs if there is issues but seems none are related to my problem.

Any ideas?

Here is the codepen: http://codepen.io/qorsmond/pen/aOPPPp

Comment: Does `html { overflow: hidden; }` help?

Comment: I tried it but it only hides the extra scrollbar. My goal is to get the md-content to be scrollable and not the whole page.

Comment: Dude Try the  class="autoScroll"  Check it hepls or Not

Comment: or this one is looking  near http://codepen.io/kpgarrod/pen/vEOLBd/

Answer (score 0):

I got the layout to display the same on MS Edge by overriding the min-height on the layout-fill on the div to 0 and it seems to work. I just don’t know why it works.

```
div > [layout-fill]{
  min-height: 0;
}
```

http://codepen.io/qorsmond/pen/vObxae

Comment: This fixed Edge for me, but still having issues in IE11.